# nth differential coefficient of $e^{-x}sinx$

Tags: calculus, derivatives, exponential-function

Question: Show that the nth differential coefficient of $e^{-x} sinx$ is $(\sqrt{2})^n$$e^{-x}sin$$(\frac{3nπ}{4} + x)$

Some of the derivatives of the function do not conform with the given nth term

First few derivatives:

$$y' = e^{-x}(cosx - sinx)\\=e^{-x}(-\sqrt{2}sin(x -\frac{\pi}{4})\\ \mathbf{y' =\sqrt{2}e^{-x}sin(x + \frac{3\pi}{4})}\\$$

$$y'' = -2e^{-x}cosx\\ =2e^{-x}(-cosx)\\ =2e^{-x}(-sin(x + \frac{\pi}{2})\\\mathbf {y'' =(\sqrt{2})^2e^{-x}sin(x + \frac{3\pi}{2})}$$

$$y''' = 2e^{-x}(sinx + cosx)\\ = 2e^{-x}(\sqrt{2}sin(x + \frac{\pi}{4})\\ \mathbf {y''' = (\sqrt{2})^3e^{-x}sin( x + \frac{\pi}{4})}$$
The third derivative doesn't conform with the given nth term

Likewise the 4th derivative:
$$\mathbf{y^{iv} = 4e^{-x}sin(x + \pi)}$$

What am I missing? can you provide a better solution to prove that the nth term is $(\sqrt{2})^n$$e^{-x}sin$$(\frac{3nπ}{4} + x)$

Comment: **Hint :** Take the imaginary part of the n-th derivative $e^{(1+i)x}$, and don't forget that $(1+i)=\sqrt{2}e^{i\pi/4}$.

Comment: Remember that $\sin$ has period $2\pi$, so $\sin(9\pi/4) = \sin(\pi/4)$ and $\sin(12\pi/4) = \sin(\pi)$.